# Bash (Yad) using floating point numbers instead of whole numbers

Tags: bash, locale, unicode

I wrote this bash [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039357/a-timer-to-set-up-different-alarms-simultaneosly/1039377#1039377) that runs multiple timers. The problem is my array stores whole numbers:

```
|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1
```

But the other user's `LC_NUMERIC` is setup as `it_IT.UTF-8` and their bash array is very different:

```
1,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000‌​000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|0,000000|1,000000
```

This causes my script to break when testing if an array entry is greater than zero:

```
iActiveTimersCount=0
for ((i=0; i<MAX_TIMERS; i++)); do
    if [[ ${aDuration[i]} -gt 0 ]] ; then
        (( iActiveTimersCount++ ))
        iAllTimersSaveSec=$(( iAllTimersSaveSec + ${aDuration[i]} ))
    fi
done
```

#### Command line tests

These tests can confirm what bash is "thinking":

```
$ if [[ 30,000000 -gt 0 ]]; then echo TRUE ; else echo FALSE ; fi
FALSE

$ if [[ 30.000000 -gt 0 ]]; then echo TRUE ; else echo FALSE ; fi
bash: [[: 30.000000: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".000000")
FALSE
```

#### Other Info

I've tried (via chat) getting other user to use `export LC_ALL=C` and export `LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"` all to no avail.

***How can bash be forced to use whole numbers (integers)?***

---

### Solution

The problem was YAD (Yet Another Dialog) storing numbers with decimal precision in Italy but not in North America. The solution was to use:

```
    # When LC_NUMERIC=it_IT-UTF8 30 seconds can be `30,000000` or
    # `30.000000` which breaks bash tests for `-gt 0`.
    # Search and replace ".000000" or ",000000" to null
    sed -i 's/[,.]000000//g' "$res1"
    sed -i 's/[,.]000000//g' "$res2"
```

Comment: That isn't floating point.  I take it your question is essentially "How do I remove these commas?"

Comment: Remove all `,000000`?

Comment: @Cyrus for other nations they might need to remove `.000000` or even different number of floating points I guess, ie `.00`.

Comment: In some locales, a comma is used instead of a period to indicate a decimal point.  In that case, the Bash script would be attempting to process real numbers instead of integers.   However, Bash only supports integers.

Comment: Why don't you just set `LC_ALL` or `LC_NUMERIC` to the appropriate locale string in your script?

Comment: @Kusalananda That is the method I was seeking help with in the first place. I'm wondering if it is `yad` that is seeing the Italian locale and overriding the bash convention for integers.

Comment: You can just set them and export them in your script.

Comment: @Kusalananda As outlined in the question, I did try having other user `export LC_ALL=C` before running the script and he reported no  change.

Comment: You don't know if they managed to do that correctly (and then ran the script from that same shell session). You don't know whether they have `BASH_ENV` set to a script that resets it to some other locale. Just set the variables in the script itself. It is unreasonable to have the user change their global locale just to have your script working.

Comment: Answers (solutions) should go in the Answer box, not in the Question, please.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Unix & Linux doesn't allow you to add new answers to closed questions. Should it be reopened, someone post a comment and I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
iActiveTimersCount=0
for ((i=0; i<MAX_TIMERS; i++)); do
    dur=$(awk -F, '{print $1}' <<<"${aDuration[i]}")
    if [[ $dur -gt 0 ]] ; then
        (( iActiveTimersCount++ ))
        iAllTimersSaveSec=$(( iAllTimersSaveSec + dur ))
    fi
done
```

Comment: Well that is a great brute force answer. I was hoping for something universal for LC / locale to work across all applications and scripts for user. But I'll try this method in the time being and report back. Thank you.

Comment: I copied the other user's test data to my own configuration file `~/.multi-timer` but the problem I have is when I run the script bash is automatically converting their floating point number `30.000000` to `30` when populating the array `${aDuration[i]}` when reading the file. This makes it impossible for me to run the `awk` command on my system because it isn't broken in the first place.

Comment: the `awk` command should work fine in either scenario.  `echo 30 | awk -F, '{print $1}'` should return 30

Comment: Depending on locale, `,` can be used as decimal point. So variable for 30 seconds could be `30,000000` or `30.000000`. I'm leaning towards fixing values when array is read, rather than each program usage. For example: `while [[ $iCurrTimerElapsedSec -lt $iCurrTimerSaveSec ]]; do` and `sleep $iLastSleepSec` lines might also have to be changed. This indicates fixing variables as they are read from disk using `var=${var%%.*}` followed by `var=${var%%,*}`. As I said I have to get other user to test, because on my system bash automatically converts floating point to integer / whole number.

Comment: You could handle either in one operation with something like `${var%%[.,]*}`

Comment: I've revised my question using your answer and comments. The OP can test tomorrow and then I'll update the script posted in Ask Ubuntu if all is well. I'd like to accept your answer right away but it is best for them to respond from Italy first. Thanks again.

Comment: Your answer was close to the solution so I've accepted it. Thanks.